# Divider lines causing header and footer issues on WordPress website using Elementor and Envato template

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, navbar

### The Issue

I'm facing a problem with my WordPress website designed using `Elementor` and an `Envato template`. Divider lines are appearing between my `header`and `footer`sections, which makes my website look unattractive as my logo and navigation bar are positioned under these lines. Additionally, there's a `footer` **divider line** displaying 'Powered by WordPress,' and I want to remove it. How can I resolve these **divider line** issues and improve the overall appearance of my website? Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

This is what it looks like:

#### Header[image]

#### Footer  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find their CSS classes and force 0px for them on custom CSS:

```css
.footer { border-top: 0px !important; }
.header { border-bottom: 0px !important; }
```

Comment: how do you find their css classes?

Comment: So when I wrote put your code, it told me "Use of !important values of 0 should have units specified". So I did this ``.header {
  border-bottom-width: 0; /* Set the bottom border width to 0 */
  border-bottom-style: none; /* Remove the border style */
}`` and it still didnt work

Comment: The best way is to use inspect element in the browser, where you can find both the class and the file.